# Microsoft Graph 502 Bad Gateway - Failed to execute backend request when creating a private channel (beta API)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a private channel in a Team using the Microsoft Graph API. I'm using the `beta` API because the `membershipType` (to make the channel private) is not available in the `1.0` API. My code was working fine until yesterday, now I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error, with message `Failed to execute backend request.` :

```
Server error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{my-team-id-is-here}/channels` resulted in a `502 Bad Gateway` response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadGateway",
    "message": "Failed to execute backend request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2ceece83-e3ff-455d-bc7b-b82f5454269f",
      "date": "2020-04-17T12:45:12"
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON body sent with this request :

```
displayName = "Private Channel Test"
membershipType = "private"
description = "Test"
```

I have all the privileges in my `AccessToken` and I am `Owner` of this team. If I switch to the `1.0` API with the same code, the channel get created, but is public, which is correct because the `membershipType` is not available in this API, but here I need to create private channels, not public.

The scope of my Token :

`Files.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All GroupMember.Read.All offline_access openid People.Read.All profile Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.Read.All`

Did anyone ever had this problem, and a solution?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same as of yesterday (17th Apr) without any code change.  Wondering if there's a Microsoft issue with a recent graph api patch..? Also getting the same response when creating a Team

Comment: My app is now working without changes - MSFT must have fixed something...

Comment: I still have the same problem in my app. Hope MSFT will fix this soon.

Comment: My problem is with creating a private Channel, not a Team.

Comment: I made multiple tests before getting this error. I always delete my test channels before trying to create new ones, with a different name because the channel doesn't seem to be deleted permanently, I get an error telling my that this name is already in use if I don't change the channel name I try to create. I read that there is a limit of 30 channels per team, maybe I reached this limit.

Comment: According to this they raised the limit to 200 https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/18635230-channel-limit-increase-beyond-200-limit

Comment: @PhatBuck Each team can have a maximum of 30 private channels and each private channel can have a maximum of 250 members. The 30 private channel limit is in addition to the 200 standard channel limit per team. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I reached the limit of 30 private channels, even though my private channels are all «deleted», they are still available to restore for 30 days, after what they are permanently deleted. I tested with a new Team and my code is working fine.

It would be nice to have a detailed error, I wouldn't have spent time debugging what is not really a bug.

When trying to create a private channel from Microsoft Teams, I get the error «Your team has reached the maximum number of private channels.». I should have tried this before...

More information here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully creating private channels using the v1.0 API, because it's supported now.

The JSON content of the request requires at least one owner.

I recieved this error when I (accidentally) attempted to specify owners in the JSON that weren't members of the Team.